# Openstack4j: Error 400 authenticate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'

Tags: java, maven, openstack

using openstack4j, the OpenStack SDK for Java, I have an error when I try to authenticate.

```
OSClient os = OSFactory.builder().endpoint("http://enpoint:5000/v2.0/")
                .credentials("***", "***").tenantName("****").authenticate();
```

The error is:

```
400 authenticate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

The library is included using maven as decumented [here](http://www.openstack4j.com/learn/getting-started/#authenticate), using this dependency;

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.pacesys</groupId>
  <artifactId>openstack4j</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
  <classifier>withdeps</classifier>
</dependency>
```